# How do i keep my background image covering the screen when scrolling / resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

What i'm trying to do is parallax scrolling through several images, but somehow 
1) Tiling happens (image keeps repeating or it doesn't show the full image) and
2) When i try different screen sizes (especially mobile phones), it doesn't work cos the image doesn't resize.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("http://cdn.udderlypettable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Maine-Coon-Face.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I've put my code on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/yhchang/pen/eZWKeY)

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: cover`. This way your background-image would resize/crop according to the parent `div` size.

Comment: Thanks! This however only partially solves the problem... I've updated the codepen, and if you look in there, the tiling still happens (albeit vertically), and if i use background-repeat: no-repeat, then there will be a lot of white space as you scroll down further due to positioning and it doesn't show the full image..